How can I make a transition for appending a child which increases the offset height in HTML, JS, or CSS?
When I try to append a child to an element, it increases the offset height of the element. Even when a transition is used, it just appends the child instantly. I just want to make a transition for that.


const p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerText = "Sample text";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(p);
div#main {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
<div id="main"></div>




Same idea as @ Rory McCrossan. You can also set its height to 0 or font-size to 0 and transition it to the desired height font-size

You can animate the height but when appending the child, the browser calcualtes the new height instantly, and the transition does not apply by default. We need set the height explicitly and then trigger the transition.
I have a simple solution for your problem using Javascript. Here we need to use css animation property to achieve the desired result. This is how I solved this  problem.
I have added window.click event. So you can try clicking on the window to check animation for every elements appeded.
I've written some comments to the code for better clarity and if anything is unclear feel free to ask, it would be my pleasure to help you.


(() => { // created a block for avoiding potential naming conflicts and keeping the global namespace clean.

  const animationDuration = 500;
  let animationTimeoutId = null;
  const main = document.getElementById("main");
  
  insertChild();
  window.onclick = insertChild;
  
  function insertChild() {
    setPreviousHeight();
    
    // Your code to insert a "p" element.
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = "Sample text";
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(p);
    
    
    setCurrentHeight();
    animate();
  }
  
  function setPreviousHeight() {
    main.style.setProperty('--previous-height', main.scrollHeight+'px');
  }

  function setCurrentHeight() {
    main.style.setProperty('--current-height', main.scrollHeight+'px');
  }

  function setAnimation() {
    main.style.setProperty('animation', `animate-height ${animationDuration}ms ease`);
  }

  // removing "animation" property is needed to animate multiple time (whenever new content is appended).
  function clearAnimation() {
    main.style.removeProperty('animation');
    clearTimeout(animationTimeoutId);
  }

  function animate() {
    // Clears the previous timeout to prevent the new animation from being interrupted
    // by the timeout set by any earlier animation.
    clearTimeout(animationTimeoutId);

    // Sets the CSS animation to run the height transition
    setAnimation();

    animationTimeoutId = setTimeout(clearAnimation, animationDuration);
  }
  
})();
/**
* I have removed transition property to use animation property.
* --previous-height variable is used to animate only new appended content height.
*/
div#main {
    --previous-height: 0px;
    --current-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden; /* required */
}

/* Replaced transition with this animation keyframe. */
@keyframes animate-height {
    from {
        height: var(--previous-height);
    }

    to {
        height: var(--current-height);
    }
}
<div id="main"></div>




You need to append the element as invisible/hidden, then animate its transition to being visible. Also note that your current transition is targeting the #main element, which is always in the DOM as soon as the page loads, not the p element you dynamically create.
Below is a working example of how to do this with an opacity fade-in, although any method would work; height/width swipes, text scrolling, blurs etc.
Note that the timeout is required to delay the removal of the class which hides the element until after it has been initially rendered to the DOM:


const p = document.createElement("p");
p.classList.add('appended');
p.innerText = "Sample text";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(p);

setTimeout(() => {
  p.classList.remove('appended');
}, 25);
div p {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

div p.appended {
  opacity: 0;
}
<div id="main"></div>




I want to make a transition for the height itself.

As I mentioned earlier and following the same idea of @Rory McCrossan you can use either height or font-size to set the transition as well


const p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerText = "Sample text";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(p);
setTimeout(()=>{p.classList.add('initial')},100)
setInterval(()=>{console.log(p.offsetHeight)},0.5)
p{
font-size : 0px;
transition: font-size 2s ease;
}

.initial{
font-size: 30px;
transition: font-size 2s ease;
}
<div id="main"></div>





const p = document.createElement("p");

document.getElementById("main").appendChild(p);
setTimeout(()=>{p.classList.add('initial')},100)
setTimeout(()=>{p.innerText = "Sample text"},1000)
setInterval(()=>{console.log(p.offsetHeight)},0.5)
p{
height : 0px;
transition: height 1s ease;
background-color:yellow;
}

.initial{
height: 30px;
transition: height 1s ease;
}
<div id="main"></div>




You can get the effect you want with css by using the @keyframes rule:

The @keyframes CSS at-rule controls the intermediate steps in a CSS animation sequence by defining styles for keyframes (or waypoints) along the animation sequence. This gives more control over the intermediate steps of the animation sequence than transitions.

For vertical control, you can use the transform: translateY(N) rule, specifying translateY(-100%) at the beginning and translateY(0) at the end of the animation.


const p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerText = "Sample text";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(p);
div#main {
  animation: fromTop 0.5s ease;
}

@keyframes fromTop {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
<div id="main"></div>




You may also transition between  max-height values based on the calculated scrollHeight of #main


const main = document.getElementById("main");

function appendContent(){
  main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<p>Sample text</p>`);

  // update height
  let height = main.scrollHeight;
  main.style.maxHeight = `${height}px`;
}
#main {
  /* inital height collapsed */
  max-height:0;
  transition: max-height 2s ease;
  overflow:hidden;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc
}
<p><button onclick="appendContent()">append content</button>
</p>
<div id="main" class="content"></div>



Alternatively you may also transition between grid-row numbers. This approach requires an additional inner wrapping element:


const main = document.getElementById("main");
const innerContent = main.querySelector('.inner-content')

function appendContent(){
  innerContent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<p>Sample text</p>`);
  main.classList.add('expanded')
}
.content{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: 0fr;
  transition: grid-template-rows 1s;
  transition-delay:1s;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc
}

.inner-content{
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.expanded{
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
<p><button onclick="appendContent()">append content</button>
</p>
<div id="main" class="content">
  <div class="inner-content"></div>
</div>



See also "Keith J. Grant: "Transitioning to Height Auto (Two Ways)"

I found an issue with your first solution.
"When we set the maxHeight we should consider that when user device width changes some of the content might get hidden. That's why when transition is over we should remove maxHeight property but if we do all the content get hidden due to max-height: 0 from css. Instead we can set maxHeight = "100%" when transition is over but transition does not work with that.
You can see in the blog you mentioned "Keight J. Grant" also not used exact pixel height instead he used 100% to avoid these issues. This method is good only when we are building toggles.
